# EHCache remove by query

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

Ho can I remove all results from EHCache satisfying a criteria ?
is the only way to execute the query and iterate through the results ??

my key is a String, and i want to remove all elements starting with a given String.

Answer (score 0):

I found one remove samples in [documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/code-samples):

```
CacheManager singletonManager = CacheManager.create();
singletonManager.removeCache("sampleCache1");
```

Is it not removing all sampleCache1? Please try it!

Comment: it removes the entire cache. i'm looking for a criteria.

Comment: Are you use hibernate?